# Significato di "dar forte" in questo brano

Tags: meaning

Nel racconto *I ventitré giorni della città di Alba*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> Si dichiarò il pomeriggio festivo, la gente riempí i caffè e offriva le bibite ai partigiani. Fecero accender le radio sulla stazione di Torino e siccome Radio Torino taceva, gridavano: – Parla adesso, parla adesso! – e la presenza di tante signore e signorine patriote non era un motivo per cui non si dovesse **dar forte** del fottuto a quelli di Radio Torino.

Sapreste spiegarmi il significato dell'espressione "dar forte" nel passaggio sopra citato? Non ho trovato questa locuzione in nessuno dei dizionari che ho consultato, incluso il dizionario dei modi di dire Hoepli. Nel vocabolario Treccani, ho trovato invece le espressioni ["parlar forte" o "dir forte"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/forte1) con questo significato:

> fig.: *parlare f.*, dire il proprio parere con franchezza, con vivacità; *lo puoi dir f.*, apertamente, di cosa che si riconosce come vera e indiscutibile.

"Dar forte" nel contesto del brano sopra citato ha lo stesso significato?

Comment: A me sembra semplicemente un avverbio che modifica tutto “dar[e] del fottuto”, cioè “insultare ad alta voce quelli di Radio Torino”.

Comment: Perfettamente d'accordo con @DaG

Comment: Mmmm... Non l'avevo pensata così... ma sicuramente avete ragione.

Comment: La metto come risposta. Poi se qualcuno ha altre opinioni le esprimerà.

Comment: Concordo, a voce alta o in maniera decisa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quel “forte” sembrerebbe semplicemente un avverbio che modifica tutta la locuzione “dar[e] del fottuto”; in altre parole, nonostante la presenza delle donne, gli altri insultano ad alta voce quelli di Radio Torino.